# How to sync User stories from JIRA to Rally

Tags: rally

User will create a user story and task in JIRA and i need to sync them to (basically continous copy user stories from JIRA to RALLY) RALLY

Comment: I want to copy user stories task and sub task from jira to rally

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JIRA to CA Agile Central](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56390201/jira-to-ca-agile-central)

Answer (score 0):

You really need to think about getting something from OpsHub and the like. They have ready-made tools to do what you want. It sounds like you are taking the wrong approach and are re-inventing the wheel.

Or alternatively, you could go to the Rally help pages: https://docs.ca.com/en-us/ca-agile-central/saas/connectors